# Exposing attributes on a Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

Architectonically speaking, is exposing your API in the views (i.e using [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl)) better than rendering a JSON in the controller?

Comment: Ideally I use the view to maintain the single responsibility principle between views = render stuff, controller = manipulate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the controller should be as slim as possible. The contents of the response, be it JSON or HTML is considered view logic.

Also, I like to recommend specialized API-building gems like [Grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape). You can do fancy things like auto-generating documentation and other useful stuff with them.